# Remove data frame rows where values in group don't match R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following data frame in `R` which includes a variable for group, number, and value (in this case animal) similar to this one below but with hundreds more rows.

```
  group number     animal
1     A      1       Lion
2     A      1 Chimpanzee
3     A      2   Elephant
4     A      2      Hyena
5     B      1 Chimpanzee
6     B      1       Lion
7     B      2   Elephant
8     B      2       Lion
9     B      2      Hyena
10    B      3 Chimpanzee
```

If a number and animal in group B matches a number and animal from group A, I want to keep that row. If an animal in group B matches an animal in group A but the numbers don't match, I want to get rid of that row. So the resulting data frame looks like this, where lines 8 and 10 are removed.

```
  group number     animal
1     A      1       Lion
2     A      1 Chimpanzee
3     A      2   Elephant
4     A      2      Hyena
5     B      1 Chimpanzee
6     B      1       Lion
7     B      2   Elephant
8     B      2      Hyena
```

Are there any tricks, perhaps using `dplyr` which can give me that result?

Answer (score 2):

Using [`dplyr::semi_join()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter-joins.html) with a filtered version of the dataset, you can return rows with `number` / `animal` combinations that appear in group A:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  semi_join(
    filter(., group == "A"),
    by = c("number", "animal")
)
```

```
# A tibble: 8 × 3
  group number animal    
  <chr>  <int> <chr>     
1 A          1 Lion      
2 A          1 Chimpanzee
3 A          2 Elephant  
4 A          2 Hyena     
5 B          1 Chimpanzee
6 B          1 Lion      
7 B          2 Elephant  
8 B          2 Hyena
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just do a `group_by` on `number` and `animal`, then `filter` to only include groups that have more than 1 occurrence?

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(number, animal) %>% filter(n() > 1) %>% ungroup()

# A tibble: 8 × 3
  group number animal    
  <chr>  <int> <chr>     
1 A          1 Lion      
2 A          1 Chimpanzee
3 A          2 Elephant  
4 A          2 Hyena     
5 B          1 Chimpanzee
6 B          1 Lion      
7 B          2 Elephant  
8 B          2 Hyena
```